# How to increase spacing between lines in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

Hi
I am using C# webbrowser control in design mode to give users an ability to create templates for their work, Can I somhow decrease and increase line spacing in this control in design view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting css property `line-height`..